# A default document is not configured for the requested URL (ReturnUrl=%2f)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When I run my ASP .NET page through Visual Studio, the login page shows and the URL generated is:

```
http://localhost:2745/LoginForm.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

The URL I am expecting is:

```
http://localhost:2745/LoginForm.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fBuildOverviewForm.aspx
```

This is causing me quite a headache as I haven't changed anything in the website itself or the web config for weeks and it was working fine before that.

I have specified the loginUrl and defaultUrl in the web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="LoginForm.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="BuildOverviewForm.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

I am completely stumped, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: After successful login,is it redirecting to "BuildOverviewForm.aspx"?

Comment: @malkam, hi, no it doesn't, it throws a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: Try by removing defaultUrl in web.config and in VS and right click "BuildOverview.aspx" and set as start up page. Save and clean/rebuild solution